# UIToolBar Not Appearing on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I am trying to add a UIToolBar but it does not appear on iPhone. It shows up on an iPad though. What am I doing wrong?

```
UIToolbar *webToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        fixedSpace.width = 20.0;

        [webToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:backButton, forwardButton, flexibleSpace, refreshButton, fixedSpace, stopButton, nil]animated:NO];

        webToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - 44, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 44);
    }
    else
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpaceiPad =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
        fixedSpaceiPad.width = 460.0;

        fixedSpace.width = 50.0;

        webToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 660, 703, 44);
        [webToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:backButton, forwardButton, fixedSpaceiPad, refreshButton, fixedSpace, stopButton, nil]animated:NO];
    }

    webToolBar.delegate = self;
    [webToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    webToolBar.tintColor = kfbBlue;
    webToolBar.hidden = NO;
    [webToolBar sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:webToolBar];
```

I've also tried placing it like this. With this implementation, it shows in the correct location on iPhone 4S, 5, and 5S, but it doesn't show at all on 6 or 6 Plus.

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        NSInteger y = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - 44;
        NSInteger screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width;

        NSLog(@"Screen height = %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height);
        NSLog(@"y = %ld and width = %ld", y, screenWidth);

        fixedSpace.width = 20.0;

        // webToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, screenWidth, 44);

        [webToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:backButton, forwardButton, flexibleSpace, refreshButton, fixedSpace, stopButton, nil]animated:NO];


        if (result.height == 480)
        {
            webToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 372, 320, 44);
        }
        else if (result.height == 568)
        {
            webToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 44);
        }
        else if (result.height == 667) {
            webToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 623, 375, 44);
        }
        else if (result.height == 736) {
            webToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 692, 414, 44);
        }
```

Comment: Print out `[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height`, what does that return?

Comment: @aus10c, it returns 568.